# For loop inside function (newbie)

Tags: javascript

I would like to have some variables that my for loop uses inside a function scope (not global).

I tried to wrap the for loop inside a function like this but it results in console error:

```
function() {
    var data = livingroomTableData;
    for(var i = data[0]; i < data[1]; i++) {
        var elemvalue = data[2] + format(i) + ".png";
        livingroomTableArray[i] = elemvalue;
    }
}
```

I would like the data variable to have the values of livingroomTableData only inside this for loop (not globally). In other loops I will input a different variable into the data variable.

Oh yes, and as you can probably tell, I'm a total newbie. :S

Comment: I presume "livingroomTableData" is an array?

Comment: You have livingroomTableData then livingroomTableArray - are these different objects?

Comment: You’ve actually already achieved what you want in terms of `data` being local to the function. What console error are you getting? Note that, with your for loop conditions, unless `data[0]` is a number, `i++` will cause an error after the code in the for loop runs for the first time.

Comment: +1 for being new and still knowing not to polute the global scope.

Comment: @verimilitude Yes it is an array

Comment: @duncan Yes they are two different objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only function scope in javascript, block scope does not exist, so you can't let the variable only inside the for loop. What you could do is to create a function scope.

Code example:

```
(function(livingroomTableData) {
    var data = livingroomTableData;
    //... the rest code
})(livingroomTableData);
```

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Please read his code, he is simply wrapped the code in a function, which won't work.

Comment: @xdazz: sure — with the code as he provided, his for loop won’t ever run.

Answer (score 1):

The *big* problem is this line:

```
for(var i = data[0]; i < data[1]; i++) {
```

That means, starting with `i` as the first element of the array, do the code in the loop, incrementing `i` by one at the end of each run until `i` is not less than the second element of `data`.

I'd rewrite it to show you a working version, but its not clear what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < livingroomTableData.length; i++) {
        var data = livingroomTableData[i];
        //your code here...
    }
}
```